# How to connect two different PCs to mysql database c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have made a program (in C#) and I have used a mysql database. I want to have access to the database from a different PC using the program I have made. The other PC is on the same internet. How can I make that work?

Answer (score 0):

From [the MySql Connector/Net tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html):

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
```

The `localhost` here refers to the local computer, however you can point it at any computer's IP address or resolvable host name.

You'll also need to make sure that the computer hosting the server has port 3306 (or whatever port you are using) open for inbound connections.